# Flutter: Where the data of the stateful widget must be stored?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a stateful widget, which is supposed to visualize a user defined-class. Ideally, CardWidget should hold a reference to an instance of Card and display its contents/pass the clicks to it.

```dart
// card.dart
class Card {
  bool isFlipped_ = false;
  bool isMatched_ = false;
  final String content;
  // ...
}
```

```dart
// widgets/card_widget.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:concentration/card.dart';

class CardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<CardWidget> createState() => _CardWidgetState();
}

class _CardWidgetState extends State<CardWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

My first question is where to place an individual card: in the widget or its state? Each example I see does it differently, although the official Flutter documentation says that states exist because, compared to widgets, their lifetime is undefined. Therefore, how can any data be stored in a state if the reference to it lost when the state is destroyed?

The second question is how to avoid data duplication so cards don't get duplicated around the code? Or is it not my concern, as only the references to the actual data are passed?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. You provided a non-context example, and it has no definitive, right, or even best answer, only opinion based.

Comment: @AlexRintt I updated the question (see the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

The general guide I go by for production code is that the only data/state held in a StatefulWidget is what is needed to execute animations or some visual effect.

Otherwise, the data/state should be held in a BLoC, ViewModel, Presenter, etc.  Then you can access the information from there.